# How to run QR decomposition inside NMinimize function?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to optimize a custom function using `NMinimize` in Mathematica. The custom function contains `QRDecomposition` in it which will require the input to have real value. I tried to use "InitialPoints" in `NMinimize` but it didn't work.

Here is my custom function:

```
TotalBeadForces[xyBvec_, params_, p_] := 
 Module[ {nB, nFrame, L0, L0p, L0m, kS, kSp, kSm, f, k, km, kp, 
   secant, tangent, normal, chord, P, Fp, Fm, rp, rm, Lp, Lm, tp, tm, 
   xyBp, xyBk, xyBm, TotalForce, deltaX, Q, R, S},
  nB = Length[xyBvec[[1]]]; 
  nFrame = Length[xyBvec];
  L0 = params[[1 ;; 2 nB - 1 ;; 2]]; 
  kS = params[[2 ;; 2 nB ;; 2]];
  TotalForce = Table[Subscript[F, i, j], {i, nF}, {j, nB}];
       deltaX = Table[Subscript[x, i, j], {i, nF}, {j, nB}];
  For[f = 1, f <= nFrame, f++, { (*loop over frames*)
    For[k = 1, k <= nB, 
      k++, { (*loop over springs within each frame*)
       km = k - 1; 
       If[km < 1, km = nB]; 
       kp = k + 1; 
       If[kp > nB, kp = 1];(*m is minus, p is plus*)
       L0p = L0[[k]]; 
       L0m = L0[[km]]; 
       kSp = kS[[k]]; 
       kSm = kS[[km]];
       xyBp = xyBvec[[f, kp]]; 
       xyBk = xyBvec[[f, k]];
       xyBm = xyBvec[[f, km]];
       secant = xyBp - xyBm; 
       chord = Norm[secant]; 
       tangent = secant/chord;  
       normal = {tangent[[2]], -tangent[[1]]}; 
        P = p[[f]]*chord*normal/2; (*Modified here*)
        rp = xyBp - xyBk;  Lp = Norm[rp]; tp = rp/Lp;
        rm = xyBm - xyBk;  Lm = Norm[rm]; tm = rm/Lm;
        Fp = kSp (Lp - L0p) tp; Fm = kSm (Lm - L0m) tm;
       TotalForce[[f, k]] = Norm[P + Fp + Fm];
       deltaX[[f, k]] = Lm - L0m;
       }];
    }];
  kS = Table[kS, {nB, nFrame}];
  {Q, R} = QRDecomposition[kS];
  S =(*Norm[R.deltaX\[Transpose]]-*)Norm[Q\[Transpose] . TotalForce];
  Return[S];
  ]
```

and here is how I was going to use `NMinimize`:

```
initialParams = Table[RandomReal[], {k, 2*ns}];
constraints = Table[paramvars[[k]] > 0, {k, 2 ns}];
Solution = 
  NMinimize[{TotalBeadForces[xyBead, paramvars, Pres], constraints}, paramvars, 
      Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing", 
     "InitialPoints" -> {initialParams}}];
```

Thank you for some input on this.